# Serving several host/domain names on local machine

Tags: windows-7, vhosts

I have a local PHP server on a Windows machine and the trouble I am having is that within the main root 127.0.0.1/localhost I would like to have several folders/sites that I can call on.

At present I can do localhost/siteA or localhost/siteB with no problem, but what I would like to do is to assign these locations test domain names:

EG: localhost/siteA would be sitea.dev, localhost/siteB would be siteb.dev

Not a problem as I have set up one on the host file and vhost config files.

mysites.dev which is linked to the root/localhost. So I can use it as above

mysites.dev/siteA and mysites.dev/siteB

But I would like to give each of these sites its own vhost name as mentioned above. So I have added the following:

Hosts File

```
127.0.0.1       mysites.dev
127.0.0.1       sitea.dev
```

vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Websites\"
    ServerName mysites.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Websites\sitea\"
    ServerName sitea.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

The trouble is that whichever one I call they all seem to simply load the first one, or at least it seems like that, but without the vhost details they all still go to the root so it looks like the host file is directing them to 127.0.0.1 and that it the vhost file seems to be ignored.

SO what am I missing in order to hook up mty individual local sites?

**SOLVED:** See my answer will mark it as the correct one when i can in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your vhosts are both trying to catch anything that comes in on port 80: `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

You need to specify the vhost name to point to a particular folder:

```
<VirtualHost sitea.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Websites\sitea\"
    ServerName sitea.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost siteb.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Websites\siteb\"
    ServerName sitea.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find more info on this in the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: thanks for this but the issue was it was not calling in my vhost file,

Comment: this is ok but also when i changed then after i got it to work it would stop my networked computers from accessing them so leaving them as <VirtualHost *:80> worked on both local and networked machines. Thanks again

Comment: Unless you add `sitea.dev` and other hosts to your hosts files on the network computers it won't work. Though they can still access it through [ipadress]/[sitea].

Comment: i have added the names etc to the networked machines from the start it was the include file issue, as i could not access via both methods, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well i do feel stupid. After a long look i then noticed that in the config file it was not calling in the vhost file as i placed them in the main httpd.conf and it worked.

So i had to uncomment the following within the httpd.conf file:

```
   # Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```